# Install R 3.6.3 on elementary OS: unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management

I couldn't find R or Rstudio on the built-in Elementary app store thingie, so I'm following [instructions](https://cran.rstudio.com/) from the R project to install R in my new Elementary OS sandbox. `sudo apt-get install r-base-core` gives a common type of error.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base-core : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.29) but 2.27-3ubuntu1.2 is to be installed
               Depends: libicu63 (>= 63.1-1~) but it is not installable
               Depends: libreadline8 (>= 6.0) but it is not installable
               Recommends: r-recommended but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: r-base-dev but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: r-doc-html but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The error persists after trying the following solutions.

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/716915/dpkg-error-processing-packages-cannot-complete-install-desktop-gui-from-termina
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa (this lists many options. I tried bullets 2, 3, 4.)

I'm using version `5.1.7 Hera`. I've tried the R project instructions for Debian and Ubuntu, and I've seen people post about a similar error on Ubuntu (https://serverfault.com/questions/767684/issues-installing-r-package-r-base-ubuntu-14). Here's my `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt bionic main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt bionic main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu eoan-cran35/
```

And here's `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`:

```
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt bionic main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt bionic main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu eoan-cran35/
```

I want to know:

- Is this problem due to following instructions for Debian/Ubuntu whilst using Elementary?
- Whether or not it is due to that, how do I fix it? Surely it must be possible to install R on Linux.

Comment: Try to change `deb http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu eoan-cran35/` to `deb http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/` in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`.
Current eOS is based on Ubuntu Bionic.

Comment: This works and if you add it as an answer, I'll accept it! Thank you so much! It would also be empowering to know where to find that info -- was it online, or from an "about my computer" menu on your elementary installation?

Comment: @Guest just a remind if you want to add answer.